# Total variation as limit of diminishing partition norm.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be continuous with bounded  total variation $V_a^b(f)$  on interval $[a,b]$. For any partition $P$ let $V(P,f) = \sum_k |f(x_k) - f(x_{k-1}|$ and let $\|P\|$ be the partition norm.  I know that $V_a^b(f) = \sup_PV(P,f)$ and I want to prove that $$V_a^b(f) = \lim_{\|P\| \to 0}V(P,f).$$

I have shown that if $f$ is differentiable and $|f'|$ is integrable then by MVT

$$\sum_{k=1}^n |f(x_k) - f(x_{k-1})| = \sum_{k=1}^n |f'(c_k)|(x_k - x_{k-1}) \to \int_a^b |f'(x)|dx$$

so in this case I believe I proved convergence to total variation as $\|P\| \to 0$.

However, I am most interested when $f$ is only known to be continuous.

Comment: Using refinements of partitions in a maximizing sequence for $V_a^b(f)$, the question reduces to showing that the limit merely exists.

Comment: Look for Theorem 17 on [these notes](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~heil/6337/fall07/section3.5a.pdf).